# Como eu posso extrair vários objetos de dentro de um Array

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, arraylist

Estou com um problema, tenho um *Array* que me retorna um outro *Array* com esse grupo de objetos dentro:

```
let array = [
  {description: "Auto", amount: 15000, date: "17/02/2021"},
  {description: "Auto 2", amount: 12000, date: "17/02/2021"}
]
```

Porém isso é feito com um `forEach` desta forma:

```
let array = []

newArray.forEach((transaction, index)=> {
    array.push(AutoTransations.Convert(transaction, index))   
})

return array
```

Eu queria saber se há uma forma de passar apenas os *objetos*, não como um *Array*, desse modo eu trataria como um objeto não precisando fazer um outro `forEach` para tirar desse *Novo Array*.

Comment: Coloca uma amostra do `newArray` e explica o que o `AutoTransations.Convert()` faz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você tem é semelhante a isso, de forma bastante resumida:

```js
function get_objects() {
  const array = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array.push({
      id: i
    });
  }
  
  return array;
}

console.log(get_objects());
```

Porém, você possuirá uma sequência de objetos no retorno da sua função, que hoje é representada pelo objeto `array`. Você não tem como fugir do laço de repetição para tratá-los todos. Tem algumas alternativas que podem, de certa forma, mascará-lo.

Por exemplo, você pode converter a sua função para um gerador e assim não precisar guardar tudo em memória ao mesmo tempo:

```js
function* get_objects() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    yield {id: i};
  }
}

for (let obj of get_objects()) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Ou mesmo aplicar um mapeamento, se a operação é extração/conversão dos dados:

```js
function get_objects() {
  const array = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array.push({
      id: i
    });
  }
  
  return array;
}

const objects = get_objects();

console.log(objects.map(obj => obj.id));
```